# access list item by Fluentd

Tags: apache-kafka, fluentd

I work on a yaml file configuration of Fluentd. Input data comes from kafka as json file.
some of them are lists lik:

`{ a:[ a1:"1", a2:"2", ... ], b:"10" }` 
How can Fluentd access a range of list items (such as first 10 items) of this json.
I wrote this config to access a specific item:

`$.a[0]`

and try some config to access first 10, such as:

`$.a[0:10]`

`$.a[0-10]`

but not worked!
can you help me?

Comment: That's not valid JSON. And Kafka doesn't have "files". Are you trying to use JSONPath to process that?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your exact use case?

Comment: I explained more in continues ...

Answer (score 0):

I explain more by an example:
suppose we have this record in Fluentd:

```
"key1": 1,
"key2": 2,
"key3": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 1,
    "c": 1,
    "d": [
    {
        "d1": 1,
        "d2": 2,
    },
    {
        "d1": 1,
        "d2": 2,
    },
    {
        "d1": 1,
        "d2": 2,
    }, ...
    ]
  }
```

List ***d*** maybe has more similar items.

How can I remove/access **all** ***Key3.d.d2***?

According to [this](https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/record_transformer#remove_keys) , I handled this problem by:

`$.Key3.d[0].d2,$.Key3.d[1].d2, $.Key3.d[2].d2,...`

but this is not a good resolution because I don't know what is the length of list d.

Comment: `record_transformer` supports `enable_ruby` flag. See https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/record_transformer#enable_ruby. You can use this and customize the functionality according to your requirements in Ruby.

Comment: Thanks @Azeem
But I didn't find any instruction to select a range of list items. Did I say it right?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, that is correct. That just enables Ruby and you can use it to manipulate or handle this according to your requirements. Depending on your expertise in Ruby, you can choose however you want. You can find examples on SO for that but you'll have to do some R&D and write code yourself as you proceed.